# Why does printing list of lines from a file return an empty result?

Tags: python, list, file, for-loop

I'm reading lines from a text file like this and just trying to see what the resulting list looks like but it does not print anything, it just returns blank. As a note, I have specified the directory properly it's just not written out fully here for simplicity.

```
# Create lists
image_filter, exptime = [], []

# Read in the file
with open('C:/Users/kenna/Desktop/University/Year 4 Studies/Senior Honours Project/randytung.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        lines = line.split()
        image_filter.append(lines[2])
        exptime.append(lines[3])
        
print(image_filter)
```

Thanks

Comment: Apologies, I am relatively new to stackoverflow

Comment: Why were you expecting this to print anything?  There are no `print()` calls anywhere.

Comment: Sidebar: You don't need to do `for line in f.readlines()`. The file handle `f` is already iterable and you can simply do `for line in f`. This way python can just iterate over the lines of the file one-by-one, reading them as required. Doing `f.readlines()` makes Python read the entire file, put its lines in a list, and then iterate over the list, which can be inefficient for large files.

Comment: I thought that the fact that I already had a call to print was implied from my question, apologies, I have added it

Comment: Thanks, I've removed readlines

Comment: You say `print(image_filter)` *just returns blank*. Even if your input file is empty, it should print `[ ]`. Does it print that. or does nothing happen? If it does print `[ ]`, that suggests that the contents of your file are different from what you think they are. Put `print(line)` inside your `for` loop to discover what is really happening.

Comment: I mean blank as in nothing happens, I tried `print(line)` in the `for` loop but it also just returns nothing

Comment: Here's something you can try: This code looks fine, so maybe it is not identical to the code that's giving you trouble. Try copy-pasting the code _from your question_ into a new file, and see what happens when you run it.

Comment: Perfect thank you, it was just a stupid indentation error from the `main()` function, a good lesson for me to copy-paste the full code, thank you very much